# Checkout a file from a specific commit to a different directory

Tags: git, git-checkout

I want to do this:

```
git checkout [revision] -- [file]
```

but I want to check it out to a location outside the repository.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) can show you the contents of a file at a specific revision, and with good old redirection (`>`) you can save it to a file:

```
git show <revision>:<path> > /other/path
```